# Disallow particular file type in NSOpenPanel

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsopenpanel

I have an `NSOpenPanel`. I want to make it so that PDF-files should not be selectable.

Just as we can set "Allowed File Types":

```
NSOpenPanel *panel;
NSArray* fileTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"pdf", @"PDF", nil];
panel = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];
[panel setFloatingPanel:YES];
[panel setCanChooseDirectories:NO];
[panel setCanChooseFiles:YES];
[panel setAllowsMultipleSelection:YES];
[panel setAllowedFileTypes:fileTypes];
int i = [panel runModal];
if(i == NSOKButton){
    return [panel URLs];
}
```

my requirement is to disallow a particular file type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `NSOpenSavePanelDelegate` method [`panel:shouldEnableURL:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOpenSavePanelDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008249-CH1-SW4) for this.

The panel will ask its delegate about each URL it is displaying; check the file's extention or UTI, and return `NO` from that method for PDFs.

Alternatively, just come up with the exhaustive list of file types that you *do* support and use that for the `allowedFileTypes` array.

Comment: shouldEnableURLis not getting called i have setDelegate, do i need to set some other property as well?

Comment: No, you just need to have the method implemented on the object that you use for the delegate.